# crawler + elasticsearch integration

Tags: elasticsearch, web-crawler, search-engine, nutch

I wasn't able to find out, how to crawl website and index data to elasticsearch. I managed to do that in the combination nutch+solr and as nutch should be able from the version 1.8 export data directly to elasticsearch ([source](http://nutch.apache.org/)), I tried to use nutch again. Nevertheless I didn't succeed. After trying to invoke

```
$ bin/nutch elasticindex
```

I get:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class elasticindex
```

I don't insist on using nutch. I just would need the simpliest way to crawl websites and index them to elasticsearch. The problem is, that I wasn't able to find any step-by-step tutorial and I'm quite new to these technologies.

So the question is - what would be the simpliest solution to integrate crawler to elasticsearch and if possible, I would be grateful for any step-by-step solution.

Comment: What is this elasticindex you are using? it doesn't exist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you have a look at the River Web plugin? https://github.com/codelibs/elasticsearch-river-web

It provides a good How To section, including creating the required indexes, scheduling (based on Quartz), authentication (basic and NTLM are supported), meta data extraction, ...

Might be worth having a look at the elasticsearch river plugins overview as well: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-plugins.html#river

Since the River plugins have been deprecated, it may be worth having a look at [ManifoldCF](http://manifoldcf.apache.org/) or [Norconex Collectors](https://www.norconex.com/collectors/).

Comment: but you can use River Web as standalone

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate indexing [Common Crawl](https://commoncrawl.org/the-data/) metadata into Elasticsearch using Hadoop: 
When working with big volumes of data, Hadoop provides all the power to parallelize the data ingestion.

Here is an example that uses Cascading to index directly into Elasticsearch:
http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/TxC0CXZ3RPPK7O/Indexing-Common-Crawl-Metadata-on-Amazon-EMR-Using-Cascading-and-Elasticsearch

The process involves the use of a Hadoop cluster (EMR on this example) running the Cascading application that indexes the JSON metadata directly into Elasticsearch.

Cascading source code is also available to understand how to handle the data ingestion in Elasticsearch.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.